# awk: cmd. line:1:fatal: division by zero attempted

Tags: linux, shell, awk, bioinformatics, genome

I'm a bioinformatics student and new to bash and programming stuff.
I want to calculate genome coverage.

This is my script. I switch the real parameter with `xx` but I'm sure `xx`s are not problematic. Other students already execute this script with no error.

```
filename=$1
reference=/xx
filebase=$(basename $filename .bam)

samtools view ${filename} -F 4 -q 30 -b > ${filebase}.f.bam

genomeCoverageBed -ibam -g ${filebase}.f.bam  ${reference} > /mnt/ABC/projects/abc/def/${filebase}.cov

coverage=$(grep genome /mnt/ABC/projects/abc/def/${filebase}.cov | awk '{NUM+=$2*$3; DEN+=$3} END {print NUM/DEN}')

echo -e "${filename},${coverage}" >> coverages.txt
```

When I execute this script with

`sh ./coverage.sh /mnt/XYZ/share/sdf_rawdata/hsa/mergedbams/ghj_merged_200203.hs37d5.cons.90perc.bam`

it doesn't work and gives me: `awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: division by zero attempted and unrecognized parameter:/mnt/XYZ/share/sdf_rawdata/hsa/mergedbams/ghj_merged_200203.hs37d5.cons.90perc.bam` error
and in the coverages.txt file it only has this line:

`-e /mnt/NEOGENE2/share/compevo_rawdata/hsa/mergedbams/Ash128_all.merged.hs37d5.fa.cons.90perc.bam`, nothing more.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It means `DEN` equals zero. You did not show the content of the offending line in `$filebase.cov`, so we can't know the 3rd field and hence don't know how `DEN` has been calculated

Comment: As an aside, your script will fail if the user passes in a filename with spaces or other shell metacharacters in it. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) (TLDR: basically always).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a condition to check if `DEN` variable is NOT NULL then only do the division in `END` block of `awk` code(trying to fix OP's attempt here).

`coverage=$(grep genome /mnt/ABC/projects/abc/def/${filebase}.cov | awk '{NUM+=$2*$3; DEN+=$3} END {if(DEN){print NUM/DEN}}')`

You need not to use `grep` command along with `awk`, we could search string in `awk` itself, may be something like:

`coverage=$(awk '/genome/{NUM+=$2*$3; DEN+=$3} END {if(DEN){print NUM/DEN}}' "/mnt/ABC/projects/abc/def/${filebase}.cov")`

---

---

***Why error is coming:*** Because its sometimes your variable `DEN` is having zero values in it. Let's take an example here in shorter way(just some examples to understand the error here):

When variable `a` is NULL then also we get same error.

```
awk 'BEGIN{a="";b=1;print b/a}'
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: division by zero attempted
```

When variable `a` is zero then also we get same error:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a=0;b=1;print b/a}'
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: division by zero attempted
```

Comment: Notice also that anything which looks like `grep 'x' | awk '{ y }'` can be usefully refactored to `awk '/x/ { y }'`; see also [useless use of `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: @tripleee, Thanks, as I mentioned I was fixing OP's attempt, let me write a note for this one too.

Comment: Programs should not silently fail on bad input. Throwing the divide by zero error is clear.